OEM deb package and ubuntu version mismatch
for my thinkpad e14gen5, lenovo provide this OEM hardware support package for ubuntu 22.04 only it seems.
I want to install ubuntu 24.04.
According to this search on packages.ubuntu
There is no equivalent package for ubuntu 24.04 (nor for ubuntu 20.04)

Is there a way I could install the old OEM package onto the new ubuntu 24.04 ?
If a user is running ubuntu 22.04 with the package installed and upgrade to ubuntu 24.04, would the package get uninstalled automatically ?

Edit :
I did some digging:
oem-sutton-adair-meta seems to mainly add an new apt source from
http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com/dists/jammy/sutton
those are all the package installed by enabling the OEM package:
linux-headers-6.5.0-1023-oem 6.5.0-1023.24
linux-headers-oem-22.04d 6.5.0.1023.25
linux-image-6.5.0-1023-oem 6.5.0-1023.24
linux-image-oem-22.04d 6.5.0.1023.25
linux-modules-6.5.0-1023-oem 6.5.0-1023.24
linux-oem-22.04c 6.5.0.1023.25
linux-oem-22.04d 6.5.0.1023.25
linux-oem-6.5-headers-6.5.0-1023 6.5.0-1023.24
oem-sutton-adair-meta 22.04ubuntu3
oem-sutton-meta 22.04ubuntu3
ubuntu-oem-keyring 2021.03.26

From my analysis, It seems to be mainly a custom kernel, so I gess it would be a bad idea to install it on another version of ubuntu ?

Version number 20, 22 and 24 mean you are running Ubuntu Core. If this is not correct please edit the question and put in the correct version info.

exact version number fixed

Is there any specific functionality those custom kernels add? It may also be that the default kernel in 24.04 has already gained those drivers/functionalities

The way a custom/OEM kernel is used is this: All the hardware in your laptop has been tested, and is known to work using the OEM supplied kernel. As @ArchismanPanigrahi has pointed out: If the kernel version in 24.04 is greater than 6.5 (headers October 2023) then chances are this is not needed.  If the kernel in the supplied repository is ever greater than the default kernel, then and only then you would use it.  The reason this is done is because on older versions of Ubuntu, newer hardware was not supported, i.e., the default kernel  was less than the package supplied version.

Since the OEM package was a custom kernel for a two-year old version of Ubuntu, chances are, the drivers in the custom kernel are already packaged in the latest kernel (6.8), so you don't need a custom kernel.

Here is how to install the custom kernel, in case you want to try it out anyway. Note that it may cause problems.
You can download the .deb package from https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/all/oem-sutton-adair-meta/download, and manually install it in Ubuntu 24.04, with the following commands.
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/o/oem-sutton-adair-meta/oem-sutton-adair-meta_22.04~ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt install ./oem-sutton-adair-meta_22.04~ubuntu1_all.deb

The package does not have any Ubuntu version specific dependency.

thanks, I did some digging (cf edited post), it seems its a custom kernel, so I guess it's a bad idea to install it on  24.04 ?
